Detect multiple different drop-down options in a column and sum them together in a cell
how to make your sumifs, detect multiple different drop-down options in a column and sum them together in a cell for a budgeting sheet
=SUMIFS(E:E, "Wants" "Gifts" "Micro" "Other", D:D)

I thought it would search for those terms in my drop-downs in E:E, and then add them together in D:D as if it was doing it for a singular drop-down term for example
=SUMIF(E:E, "Wants", D:D)


Detect Multiple Different Drop-Drown and Sum Them together in a cell
you may use the Join function instead of Sumifs.
JOIN combines text from multiple cells into a single string, while SUMIFS adds up cells based on multiple criteria:
Formula used:
=JOIN( " " , C2:D2)

Expected result

Reference

Join function


If this is not your expected result. Kindly provide an MRE so that I can adjust my answer based on your requirements.

You're better off using SUMPRODUCT in this case.  SUMPRODUCT doesn't have the "argument must be a range" requirement like SUMIFS. There are various ways to write it, but perhaps the easiest is to write it like you would a FILTER.  For the first parameter, put the column that you want to sum. The for the other parameters, generate booleans arrays.
Now just like with FILTER, these boolean arrays work together as AND. So when you want multiple matches like in your case, you need to contain that all within the same parameter. It would look something like this.
=SUMPRODUCT(D:D, XMATCH(E:E,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E:E, {"Wants","Gifts","Micro","Other"})))

Which is like saying "Sum values in column D if the value in column E is "Wants" OR "Gifts" or "Micro" or "Other".
